# Clear() after append() function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have problem with add list to table. When I add list to table and after that clean list to save some new value, something weird happend with table.

```
    for i in range(1, number_of_multiplication+1):
        for j in range(1, number_of_multiplication+1):
            list.append(j*i)
        table.append(list)
        list.clear()
```

For `number_of_multiplication = 5` actual output is :

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

[[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]

[[3, 6, 9, 12, 15], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]

[[4, 8, 12, 16, 20], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]]

[[5, 10, 15, 20, 25], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]]
```

Comment: Why do you fill the list then empty it again?

Comment: A copy isn't added to the list when you do `table.append(list)`. You're adding, pupulating, and clearing the same list over and over again.

Comment: BTW, try not use list as a variable name. list is a built-in function.